# Minecraft Forge 1.7.2-1.7.10 doesn't load up after clicking launch

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This may seem like a duplicate and it might be, to I apologize in advanced if is. :O

Anyways, I've recently tried to load up minecraft with forge after wiping out my hard drive (all the data was backed up) and for some odd and unknown reason, it doesn't even pop up after clicking "Play". To add a little more information to this, the program "javaw.exe" (which is minecraft to those who don't entirely know) shows up in taskmanager for about 6-14 seconds; then proceeds to close without warning.

No sign of minecraft shows up other than that so I'm a little confused about this. I'm certain it must be a missing file of some sorts, or maybe a diffrent java compared to my previous hard drive.

I'll try to get a log of some sorts as soon as I can, but its a little difficult considering after clicking play nothing pops up. Not even a text file in the .minecraft folder.

Comment: is there an error or log?

Comment: As I said in the post, I'm trying to get one. But from what i've seen so far, nothing pops up after the launcher closes.

Comment: After doing some testing with technic launcher, ATlauncher; I've managed to find no success with them either. Regular minecraft seems to be working just fine, but as soon as forge comes in it just fails entirely. Its most likly a java problem which may need some time to figure out. I'll update when I get the results.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't provide tech support for modded Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

Alright so I found the solution to this issue...

As it turns out, Forge is only part of the issue. The main part is Java. Java 8 is for some reason compatible with forge, forcing it to basically close and not load up. No idea why, but Java 7 seems to work just fine.

Hope this helps anyone that has this issue as well.

Comment: did you mean `incompatible` ?

Comment: I can tell you that based on tweets from some of the Forge team, Forge will be on Java 8 here soon. It's odd that they're incompatible though -- usually programs written for a lower version work on a higher. I'll try bugging one of them though and see what I get.

Comment: Also is this any Forge 1.7.2-1.7.10 (i.e. both latest and recommended)? It may have been fixed in a newer version...